# Altering axes positions in ggplot scales lets hjust/vjust of theme(axis.text) to be ignored

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, axis-labels

I want to create a plot with the x-axis at the top and the axis labels rotated 90 degrees center-aligned with the ticks. This is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)

# create data
a3 <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
aaa4 <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
aaaa5 <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)

df_2 <- data.frame(a3, aaa4, aaaa5)

correlation_matrix_2 <- cor(df_2)

corr_long <- correlation_matrix_2 %>% 
  as.data.frame(.) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(., var = "V1") %>% 
  pivot_longer(., cols = -V1, names_to = "V2", values_to = "r")

# plot:
ggplot(corr_long, aes(V1, V2))+
  geom_tile(mapping = aes(fill = r))+
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, angle = 90, hjust = 0, vjust = .5))
```

However, the plot ignores the vjust parameter of the theme and always positions the labels a little bit off. This only happens when the axis is set to be at the top using position parameter from scale_x_discrete, it works fine for "bottom". The hjust works as expected in both cases.

I then tried a few other things and found that it also happens when the y axis is set to the right, but then it is hjust that is ignored and vjust works. It also happens for scale_x/y_continuous. Changing the order (theme first, then scale_x_discrete) does not change anything either and also splitting it in two separate commands does not work:

```
[...]
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 1))+
[...]
```

Is that a bug or do I miss something here?

Comment: Try using the `axis.text.x.top` argument of the `theme()` function instead of `axis.text.x` - the `vjust` argument works fine here.

Comment: Great, that works, thanks! I still don't really understand why some parameters work in either case but I am fine with the fact it works at all. If you post your comment as an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: This depends on the defaults set by the `theme`, e.g. in general `axis.text.x.top` inherits from `axis.text.x`. However, for the default `theme_grey` `vjust` is explicitly set for `axis.text.x.top` and hence will not be inherited from `axis.text.x`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! For me it would be more intuitive though if axis.text.x.top inherits from axis.text.x when scale_x_(position = "top") regardless of the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the position of the axis text at the top using the `axis.text.x.top` argument of the `theme()` function instead of `axis.text.x`. Similarly, you can use `axis.text.y.right` for y-axis text on the right hand side. For example:

```r
ggplot(corr_long, aes(V1, V2))+
  geom_tile(mapping = aes(fill = r))+
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")+
  theme(axis.text.x.top = element_text(size = 16, angle = 90, hjust = 0, vjust = .5))
```